# where to store images?

Tags: images

i am making a website that will have a big ammount of photos and images, where should i store these is a database an efficient option?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

In general, images store directly on disk will load faster, and will be cheaper to store (because, **in general**, database space is more expensive than disk space.

Answer (score 0):

The smartest way is to just have an /images/ directory that's further broken down into images/buttons, images/avatars, images/icons, or anything else that makes managing, organizing, and keeping track of them easiest for you.

But if you're getting a lot of hits and the server is being worked to display all of these pictures (many http requests), you might want to look into a [CDN](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) (or just host them elsewhere).